# Spring Custom Authentication Provider- how to return custom REST Http Status when authentication fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have custom authentication provider that works fine:

```
@Component
public class ApiAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        final String name = authentication.getName();
        final String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (isAuthorizedDevice(name, password)) {
            final List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ApiInfo.Role.User));

            final UserDetails principal = new User(name, password, grantedAuths);
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, password, grantedAuths);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
}
```

But it always return 401. I would like to change it in some cases to 429 for brute force mechanism. Instead of returning null I would like to return error: f.e.: 429. I think It should not be done here. It should be done in configuration: `WebSecurityConfig` but I have no clue how to achieve this.

I tried already throwing exceptions like:

```
throw new LockedException("InvalidCredentialsFilter");
throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Invalid Credentials!");
```

or injecting respone object and setting there status:

```
 response.setStatus(429);
```

But non of it worked. It always return 401.

F.e.:

```
  curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1.0/time   --header "Authorization: Basic poaueiccrmpoawklerpo0i"
{"timestamp":"2022-08-12T20:58:42.236+00:00","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","path":"/api/v1.0/time"}%
```

And body:

> Whitelabel Error Page

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
> Fri Aug 12 22:58:17 CEST 2022
> There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).

Also could not find any docs or Baeldung tutorial for that.

Can You help me?

P.S My WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig {

    AuthenticationProvider apiAuthenticationProvider;


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .authenticationProvider(apiAuthenticationProvider)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(ApiInfo.BASE_URL + "/**")
                .fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: `But non of it worked` did not work how? what was expected, how did it turn out what was returned etc? also. Docs for spring security is on their webpage. Just because there isn't a Baldung page for it, does not mean there is not information. Baeldung is not the official documentation.

Comment: F.E. here is same examaple with throwing error:
https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-security

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228358/why-are-my-questions-on-stack-overflow-getting-downvotes-without-explanation

Comment: im answering question because i take free time out of my day answering questions. I dont spend hours solving your question, because i dont get payed solving your question. I downvoted because how to handle exceptions is in the spring security official documentation if you read the chapter on `architecture` which is a chapter you should read BEFORE you code in spring security, orr post a question on stack overflow. But im going to give you a hint, what exception is he throwing, and what exception are you throwing... not all exceptions are the same.

Answer (score 0):

As I did not useful answer I will post my solution.

Generally I've added custom implementation of AuthenticationEntryPoint, which handles all unauthorized request and it is proceeded after AuthenticationProvider:

```
@Component
public class BruteForceEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    final BruteForce bruteForce;
    static final String WWW_AUTHENTICATE_HEADER_VALUE = "Basic realm=\"Access to API\", charset=\"UTF-8\"";

    public BruteForceEntryPoint(BruteForce bruteForce) {
        this.bruteForce = bruteForce;
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        addWwwAuthenticateHeader(request, response);
        bruteForce.incrementFailures(request.getRemoteAddr());
        if (bruteForce.IsBlocked(request.getRemoteAddr())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS.value());
            OutputStream responseStream = response.getOutputStream();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.writeValue(responseStream, HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS);
            responseStream.flush();
        } else {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
            OutputStream responseStream = response.getOutputStream();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.writeValue(responseStream, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            responseStream.flush();
        }
    }

    void addWwwAuthenticateHeader(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (isWwwAuthenticateSupported(request)) {
            response.addHeader(WWW_AUTHENTICATE, WWW_AUTHENTICATE_HEADER_VALUE);
        }
    }
}
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig {

    AuthenticationProvider apiAuthenticationProvider;
    AuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    public WebSecurityConfig(AuthenticationProvider apiAuthenticationProvider, AuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint) {
        this.apiAuthenticationProvider = apiAuthenticationProvider;
        this.customAuthenticationEntryPoint = customAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return
                http
                        .httpBasic()
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                        .and()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers(AapiInfo.BASE_URL + "/**").authenticated()
                        .and()
                        .authenticationProvider(apiAuthenticationProvider)
                        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                        .and()
                        .csrf().disable()
                        .formLogin().disable()
                        .logout().disable()
                        .build();
    }
```